# can we override the default styles of selector with custom css in angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have default styles set for a control (button), selector is app-button, btn in button.css

```
<button class="btn">{{SampleText}}</button>
```

**button.css**

```
.btn { 
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Calibri;
background-color: white;}
```

In other application i am using this button with the customized style in the sample.css, do not want to have default class btn.

```
<app-button class="Newbtn" >Hello</app-button>
```

**sample.css**

```
.btn { 
font-size: 25px;
font-family: Calibri;
background-color: Red;}
```

I tried with Input decorator,  @Input() Class: string;

```
<button [ngClass]="'btn'">{{SampleText}}</button>
<app-button [Class]="'Newbtn'" >Hello</app-button>
```

this isnt't taking the Newbtn styles declared in sample.css. if i have Newbtn class inside button.css it will take, but i don't want to do that.

if I don't give any styles it is picking btn styles which is correct in my case. but I should also be able to override the default styles mentioned in button.css with new styles in sample.css.

Please suggest me if i want to customize the default styles how can i make it?

Comment: What are you doing with the Class input inside app-button component? Is it being directly tied to a button's ngClass?

Comment: yes, that's the other way, but i don't want to use any css class inside button.css, i want to use sample.css class. I have updated the question with the css styles.

Comment: As per your code above you can change the name of the class in sample.css and pass the css name from parent component. (parent component) <hello name="{{ name }}" [cssClassName]="'btn-green-class'"></hello> (child component) <button class="{{cssClassName}}">Green</button><br/>
<button [ngClass]="[cssClassName]">Another button</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AppButtonComponent` should be like this:

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
    <button [class]="Class ? Class : 'btn'">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
  `
})
export class AppButonComponent {
  @Input() Class: string;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```html
<app-button>Original Button</app-button>

<app-button Class="custom-css">Custom Button</app-button>
```

The important thing here is that `custom-css` class is global. You can declare it inside styles.css.

Probably you have your own css files (let's suppose, `default-styles.css`) and you want to build another file containing your custom styles (let's suppose, `custom-styles.css`). You have to declare the existence of both files inside `angular.json`, as siblings of `styles.css` in styles array:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/default-styles.css",
  "src/custom-styles.css"
],
```

You can see an example on this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma613860396433166).

Answer (score 0):

Example:- 
Parent Component. HTML

```
 <hello name="{{ name }}" [cssClassName]="'btn-green-class'"></hello>
```

Child Component. HTML

```
  <button class="button {{cssClassName}}">Green</button><br/>
<button [ngClass]="['button', cssClassName]">Another button</button>
```

Child Component. TS file
   @Input() name: string;
   @Input() cssClassName: string= "button-background-yellow";

Style.css

```
   .btn-green-class{
background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.button { border: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button-background-yellow{
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

Comment: I am creating re-usable component and used in other project. I expose the module for the same.Component i dont keep 2 buttons. all i have one button with default class provided, when ever i use with selector i pass customized css class or if i dont pass it should take default css class. and where do u hv style.css? why do u need name here?

Comment: I have updated the code, now you can override your class based on your needs. If you did not pass any class it will take the default one else it will take the given class. Try to remove the code [cssClassName]="'btn-green-class'" from parent component